# How to remove the data-range sign if the data is zero on y axis of highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

How to remove the G sign below for zero

[image]

Comment: Probably best to provide sample code.  Even better would be to place in a plunker or jsfiddle example so people can provide concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the label `formatter()` function.
This will required that you create the logic to use the abbreviation yourself as well, however.

**Example:**

```
yAxis: { 
    labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        return this.value == 0 ? 0 : this.value / 1000000000 + 'G';
    }
  }
}
```

**Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/131/

Something more flexible could look like this:

```
yAxis: { 
    labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        var val;
      if(this.value > 1000000000 ) {
        val = this.value / 1000000000  + 'B';
      }
      else if(this.value > 1000000) {
        val = this.value / 1000000 + 'M';
      }
      else if(this.value > 1000) {
        val = this.value / 1000 + 'k';
      }
      else {
        val = this.value;
      }
        return this.value == 0 ? 0 : val;
    }
  }
}
```

updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/132/

Comment: This method restrict the data on y-axis only to 'G' .but i need it fexible ( like if the data is in thousand it should show 'K' in million then 'M' etc.)

Comment: Then you need to make it more complex, with a series of if statements, or a switch statement, for each level that want to cover.